# Swift 2: Crash when using SKAction

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

When i try to run this code i get this error:

CUICatalog: Invalid Request: requesting subtype without specifying idiom
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Anyone know how i can fix this?

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
 _ = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("makeEnemiesTowards"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

func makeEnemiesTowards() {

    let spawnEnemiesTowards = SKAction.waitForDuration(0.5)
    let removeEnemiesTowards = SKAction.removeFromParent()
    let moveAndRemoveEnemiesTowards = SKAction.sequence([spawnEnemiesTowards, removeEnemiesTowards])

    let enemyTowardsTexture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "player")
    let enemyTowards = SKSpriteNode(texture: enemyTowardsTexture)
    enemyTowards.position = CGPoint(x: CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), y: CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    enemyTowards.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false
    enemyTowards.zPosition = 5
    enemyTowards.runAction(spawnEnemiesTowards)

    self.addChild(enemyTowards)

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is the problem, however in SpriteKit if you want to invoke a method forever you should **not** use `NSTimer` but `SKAction`.

Replace your `didMoveToView` with this.

```
override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    let addEnemy = SKAction.runBlock { [weak self] in self?.makeEnemiesTowards() }
    let wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)
    let sequence = SKAction.sequence([addEnemy, wait])
    SKAction.repeatActionForever(sequence)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, the app is running now, but the sprite doesn't spawn. Any idea why?

Comment: @Gjeruldsen: You are running this action `enemyTowards.runAction(spawnEnemiesTowards)` which basically does nothing (just waits for 0.5 secs). You should run `moveAndRemoveEnemiesTowards` instead if you want the enemy to disappear after half a second.

Comment: @Gjeruldsen: Please describe me the behaviour you need. You want the sprite to move? In which direction?

Comment: The player is affected by gravity which makes him move to the right. I want the player to pass sprites that is made using this method.

Comment: @Gjeruldsen: I'm sorry but I don't understand what you need. However I think the error described in your question has been fixed so you should accept my answer, create a new question and carefully describe what you need.

Answer (score 1):

So basically the error is because you are trying to unwrap an optional type meaning some thing like (String?). But it is nil so this is not possible.

I believe this is the line that causing you to fail. physicsBody is most likely null.
  `enemyTowards.physicsBody!.affectedByGravity = false`

Hope it helps